# Why my R couldn't open a file when it's exist

Tags: r, r-sf

I am trying to make a London map in R

I have downloaded the shapefile with all of London Wards. https://data.london.gov.uk/dataset/statistical-gis-boundary-files-london

My following code (first line) keeps showing an error.

```
london_wards_sf<-read_sf(here("london-wards-2018_ESRI","London_Ward.shp"))
london_wgs84<-london_wards_sf
st_transform(4362)
stop_search_data_3 <-st_as_sf(stop_search_data_1,
                              coords=c("longitude","latitude"),
                              crs=4326)
```

already check spelling, working dir but still cannot find files that are existing

Comment: What kind of error? Can you copy it?

Comment: Error in here("london-wards-2018_ESRI", "London_Ward.shp") : 
could not find function "here"

Comment: `library(here)`

Comment: and when I delete "here"  it then turn out "can't find a file"

Comment: ok, I suspect you don't have files in your "working directory". Can you confirm that they are there?

Comment: after library (here) Error: Cannot open "/Users/xxdehh/Desktop/london-wards-2018_ESRI/London_Ward.shp"; The file doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: Do you have this two files on your Desktop?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239261/discussion-between-kris-and-bloxx).

Comment: It seems like the error is just that you're giving the wrong path to the file. Without access to your computer, it's hard for anyone to figure that out for you, though. Carefully work back through where your files are in relation to where your code is being run from

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the comments, you should organize your files and read further into calling files from different folders, and the relevant R syntax.

As an alternative/temporary approach, you can also try the following and see if this works

```r
temp <- tempfile()
download.file("https://data.london.gov.uk/download/statistical-gis-boundary-files-london/08d31995-dd27-423c-a987-57fe8e952990/London-wards-2018.zip",temp)
londow_ward_shp <- unzip(temp, files='London-wards-2018_ESRI/London_Ward.shp')
read_sf(londow_ward_shp)
```